# (Java) Как на линейном графике (LineChart) от Mpandroidchart подписывать только определенные точки?

Tags: java, android, диаграммы

мне нужно срочно подписать значения на графике вдоль кривой, но не все, а только определенные значения, например по индексу значений (или еще как):

```
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
/***************************************/
entries.get(i)
```

Чтобы выглядело примерно так: [image: Подписаны и выделены только некоторые значения графика]